# Calculate the resistance between 2 adjacent nodes on a shape using graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, physics

In shapes like regular octahedron or dodecahedron, how can Graph Theory be used to calculate the resistance between two adjacent vertices? All edges are assumed to have unit resistance. Is there anything **above** the usual way to approach physics problems about cicuits?

[image: Dodecahedron]

Comment: Depends on how you define "resistance"...

Comment: @5xum Now is it okay?

Comment: So are we talking electrical resistance here?

Comment: @5xum Yes, or resistance distance as stated in this link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_distance

Comment: Are you familiar with the basics like serial and parallel resistance? Is this an exercise with a known nice solution or did you make that up yourself?

Comment: @GDumphart Well, I don't know the solution for both, but for the dodecahedron it is $R = \frac{19}{30}$, and I know this is "solvable" question because when I googled it, many textbooks came up with this in the Exercise section. And yes, I am familiar with the basics. I also know that the problem regarding the regular dodecahedron can be solved using "symmetry".

Comment: There are many connections between electrical flows and graph theory. Some search terms are: "electrical flow laplacian",  "electrical graph theory", "electrical circuit networks graph".